# Cython memoryviews error: Invalid index for memoryview specified

Tags: python, cython, memoryview

I'm trying to implement standard quicksort in cython using memoryviews. Here is my code:

```
def quicksort_cython(double[:] l):
    _quicksort(l, 0, len(l) - 1)


cdef void _quicksort(double[:] l, double start, double stop):
    cdef double pivot, left, right, tmp
    if stop - start > 0:
        pivot = l[start]
        left = start
        right = stop
        while left <= right:
            while l[left] < pivot:
                left += 1
            while l[right] > pivot:
                right -= 1
            if left <= right:
                tmp = l[left]
                l[left] = l[right]
                l[right] = tmp
                left += 1
                right -= 1
        _quicksort(l, start, right)
        _quicksort(l, left, stop)
```

However, during the compilation with standard `setup.py` file and `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` command I get multiple errors regarding the memoryview access:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...


cdef void _quicksort(double[:] l, double start, double stop):
    cdef double pivot, left, right, tmp
    if stop - start > 0:
        pivot = l[start]
                      ^
------------------------------------------------------------

quicksort_cython_opt3.pyx:9:23: Invalid index for memoryview specified
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong? Also any performance improving tips will be appreciated as I'm new to Cython.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically doubles can't be indices (should be ints). I assume that's the problem...although I'm admittedly not familiar with cython memoryviews.

Comment: Yeah.. switching to int allowed me to compile this code. Also I had to specify the type in the passed numpy array: `np.array(l, dtype=np.int32)` to make it work. Maybe it was obvious but I haven't found that in documentation so thank You.

Comment: Glad I could help!